# Yocto SDK ROS1 melodic meta-ros build

Tags: sdk, yocto, ros

we are starting to integrate the ROS layer to our Yocto build system of the company. Since our process is to provide a SDK to our application developers which can cross compile their applications suitable to the target boards which we are supporting, we are facing a problem to integrate the catkin toolchain into the Yocto SDK. We are using the ROS1 melodic version in the meta-ros branch dunfell. Using the popultate_sdk to our target it didn’t integrate the catkin toolchain at all. We bbappend the catkin recipe with the extension BBCLASSEXTEND=“native nativesdk” which builds the toolchaininto the SDK, but we are facing the issue that the paths to the catkin toolchain are not working if we source the environment script of the SDK as described in the Yocto manual. But anyway I am not sure if this is the correct way to integrate the catkin toolchain into the SDK.
So basically:
Is there a documentation/manual to integrate the catkin toolchain into the Yocto SDK? Are there any solutions? Did somebody tried it and get a positive result?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Which recipe are you trying to use the catkin_tools to build with?

when you add

`BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"`

this results in two different recipes being built that any other recipe can depend on.

Including the BBCLASSEXTEND would mean that the catkin-%.bb recipe then creates the nativesdk-catkin and catkin-native targets. These targets are used in other recipes as such:

`DEPENDS = "catkin-native"`

and like all recipes being DEPEND upon, they will show up in either ${RECIPE_SYSROOT_NATIVE} or ${RECIPE_SYSROOT}

Comment: I use the catkin recipe itself. I just created a bbappend file in my custom layer to the main recipe in the meta-ros, which is located in meta-ros/meta-ros1-melodic/generated-recipes/catkin/, since I am using ROS1 melodic for our current project. The Yocto SDK has install the ROS1 melodic middleware in the sysroots/ folder. I can see. But I cannot build ROS applications using the SDK since it is incomplete somehow. I can only build it in the target hardware itself. And this is not the canonical way to do it in the Yocto PRoject since the target platform is not meant to be used as build system

Comment: Sorry I forgot to respond for a bit. Is there any update on this, or is it still stuck?

Comment: No we source the ROS toolchain in the target hardware itself to build the ROS application natively. We didn't figure out yet how to use the Yocto SDK properly with the ROS middlware since some PATH variables are missing in the environment. And we get some errors. Googling the answer, most resposnes are to build it natively on the target hardware but in my opinion this is not the way to go since we watnt o distribute the SDK to the application guys without delivering the hardware to them since hardware is a limited resource here.

Comment: Yeah, that is not the yocto way of doing it.

Some repositories do not support cross-compilation well, and hard-coded paths and environment variables are a big sign of that.

can you share the exact repository you are pulling from?

Comment: https://github.com/ros/meta-ros -> commit 5f8eaceece856f892602753d79e9f19920c4d077